# Способ хранения динамических параметров в БД на товары

Tags: asp.net, база-данных, моделирование, php, sql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, основные способы хранения динамических параметров на товары в базе. Т.е. есть несколько параметров, которые могут быть, а могут и не быть у разных товаров. Как сделать, чтобы меньше места занимало, чтобы быстро и просто можно было их извлечь, добавлять и удалять. Нельзя также забывать и о значениях самих параметров. Думаю, что этот вопрос многих интересует, т.к. товарные группы могут быть у интернет-магазинов абсолютно разные, соотв. и параметры тоже. Какое на ваш взгляд решение близко к истине? (EAV, 1 параметр на 1 столбец, ну и тд).

А также чтобы по ним можно было делать сортировку и сравнение

Answer (score 1):

Да, EAV для обобщенного интернет-магазина наилучший вариант. Фильтры, сравнения, настройка разных свойств для разных групп, все это наилучшим способом реализуется и притом без изменения структуры БД.

Работать это будет приемлемо, достигается созданием правильных индексов (зависеть будет от величины каталога и количества свойств. на самом деле выбор из двух индексов там будет - составного или по одному полю). Плюс, конечно, кэширование запросов, вообще будет летать.

Хардкодить свойства можно лишь, если есть программер на зарплате и на любой чих будет менять структуру базы. Ну либо должна быть неочевидная процедура перестройки базы, сколько при этом будет оффлайна тоже не ясно, может быть слишком много.

Comment: не понял последнего абзаца, вроде EAV и создавалось, чтобы не было проблем с этим

Comment: @majatu это альтернативный вариант. Есть системы, в которых структура БД редактируется power-юзерами путем изменения метаданных, на основании которых перестраиваются таблицы, пересоздаются триггеры, хранимые процедуры. При этом достигается более высокая скорость работы запросов, но каждое вмешательство в структуру приводит к простою системы - при больших объемах базы бывает к длительному. Хорошо, когда изменений немного и нечасто они происходят. 

Участвовал в разработке такой системы, но не для веб. Поэтому голосую за EAV как более простую в реализации.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно для решения таких задач используют таблицу с большим количеством nullable-полей и дополнительную таблицу с описанием тех полей, которые используются. Но это не очень экономично для БД, а если постараться сделать запас минимальным, полей может не хватить.

Ещё можно создать View, основанные на INFORMATION_SCHEMA или других системных таблицах / представлениях СУБД, из которых можно узнать структуру таблицы и динамически её менять. Это самый эффективный, но и самый сложный способ. Кроме того, он требует того, чтобы у пользователя, под которым приложение обращается на сайт, были права на изменение структуры БД.

Наиболее простой способ - это создание метатаблиц. Одна таблица содержит список параметров, другая - значения этих параметров с внешними ключами на этот список и на расширяемую таблицу. Работать с такой таблицей придётся через динамический SQL. Поскольку данные получаются усложнёнными запросами, работать это будет медленно.